# Magento 1.9.x how to customize send email from my custom module?

Tags: magento-1.9, send-mail, email-translation

Hi i would like to customize send email and Send invoice email with attached. from my **custom module** how could i achieve this in magento1. Please find the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: find default templates in `app/locale/en_US/template/email`

Answer (score 0):

Email templates are not extension based. You can add new email templates for extension, for example when you want to send an email for a custom functionality (i.e. when you have a quote extension or something).

If you want to override your templates, there are two options:

- You can do it on the server itself. All email templates are stored in `app/locale/en_US/template/email`. If you want to have a French version, you can copy these files to `app/locale/fr_FR/template/email` and translate/change them there.
- You can do this from the Magento backend. This can be done by going to *System > Transactional Emails*. Here you can click "Add New Template". Now you can select the base template (the one for invoices) and update them there.

Be aware that a lot of mails, especially the sales emails, have a guest and logged in template. Also, it's important that you know how to use HTML if you want to change the look and feel of the emails.